Proving that the area of a step region is equal to the sum of the area of its rectangles?
Definitions and axioms
Here is how the definition of the area function, $a$ and its axioms from the book Calculus I by Tom Apostol. We assume there exists a class $\mathscr{M}$ of measurable sets in a plane and a set function $a$ whose domain is $\mathscr{M}$:

$\forall S \in \mathscr{M} : a(S) \geq 0$
If $S,T \in \mathscr{M}$, then so are $S \cup T, S\cap T \in \mathscr{M}$ and $a(S\cup T)=a(S)+a(T)-a(S\cap T)$
If $S,T \in \mathscr{M}$ such that $S \subseteq T$, then $T-S \in \mathscr{M}$ and $a(T-S)=a(T)-a(S)$
If $S\in \mathscr{M}$ and $T$ is congruent to $S$, then $T\in \mathscr{M}$ and $a(S)=a(T)$.
Every rectangle $R$ is in $\mathscr{M}$ and if $R$ have edges with lengths $w$ and $h$, then $a(R)=wh$
Let $Q$ be a set that can be enclosed by two step regions $S$ and $T$ such that $S \subseteq Q \subseteq T$. For all step regions $S$ and $T$ satisfying $S \subseteq Q \subseteq T$, if there is one and only one number $c$ satisfying the inequality $a(S) \leq c \leq a(T)$, then $Q$ is measurable and $a(Q) = c$

A rectangle $R$ is defined as any set congruent to the set,
$$\{(x,y) :(0 \leq x \leq w \wedge 0 \leq y \leq h\}$$
where $w$ is the width of the rectangle and $h$ is the height of the rectangle. It's area $a(R)$ is defined to be $w \cdot h$.
Let $k$ be any positive integer such $k \leq n$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and $R_k$ be a rectangle defined as,
$$R_k := \{(x,y) :(x_{k-1} \leq x \leq x_k \wedge 0 \leq y \leq h_k\}$$
We can define a step region $S$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$ as such:
$$S = \bigcup_{k=1}^n R_k $$
where $x_0=a$ and $x_n =b$.
Problem
Intuitively, the area of this step region will be the sum of the area of each rectangle $R_k$;
$$a(S)=\sum_{k=1}^n a(R_k)$$
I feel like I can deduce the theorem by applying Axiom (2.) repetitively. While trying to prove this theorem, I got stuck when trying to apply Axiom (2.) here.
$$a(S) = a(\bigcup_{k=1}^n R_k)$$
If every $R_k$ is disjoint, then I can ignore the $a(S \cap T)$ part as it results to $0$. However, it seems like they overlap at their boundaries. The edge of rectangle $R_k$ will overlap with the edge of $R_{k+1}$. Though it will be a line and the overlapping region will have an area of $0$, I still wish to prove it rigorously. Also, I want to prove that the rectangles will only overlap with their neighboring rectangle. I feel like I can prove this by induction but I'm not really sure how to start and move forward with it. I'd appreciate any assistance to help me move forward with this proof, especially when trying to apply Axiom (2.).

Yes, edges can overlap, but it does not matter as their intersection has area $0$ (because their intersection is included in a line segment, whose area is $0$ by your Axiom (5.)). By induction on $n\geq 2$, you can show the following : if $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ are sets in $\cal M$ with $a(S_i\cap S_j)=0$ for any $i \neq j$, then $a(\bigcup_{k=1}^n S_k)=\sum_{k=1}^n a(S_k)$. The base case $n=2$ follows from Axiom (2.)

@EwanDelanoy How do I go on to show that if any two rectangles $R_k$ and $R_l$ such that $k \neq l$ overlap, then the area of their intersection is $0$?

Look at the definition of $R_k$ and the constraint on the abscissa $x$ (you probably forgot to mention a condition like $a=x_0\lt x_1 \lt x_2 \lt \ldots \lt x_n=b$ ; then $R_k$ and $R_l$ ($l\neq k$) can intersect only if $l=k-1$ or $k=k+1$, in which case any $(x,y)$ in the intersection must satisfy $x=x_k$).

Start by proving the following proposition: For any $b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$, let $L$ be the set of $(x,y)$ with $x = b$ and $c \leq y \leq d$ (ie $L$ is an arbitrary vertical line segment). Then $L$ is measurable and $a(L) = 0$.
To prove this proposition, we first express $L$ as the intersection of the rectangles $A$ and $B$, where $A$ and $B$ have top and bottom edges at $y = d$ and $y = c$, $A$ has left edge $x = b - 1$ and right edge $x = b$, and $B$ has left edge $x = b$ and right edge $x = b+1$. This implies that $L$ is measurable by Properties 5 and 2.
Showing $a(L)$ must be zero is trickier. The idea here is that if $L$ has any positive measure, we can reach a contradiction because $L$ can be expressed as a subset of a rectangle with even smaller measure.
More formally, suppose $a(L) > 0$. Then any rectangle containing $L$ must have measure $\geq a(L)$ by Properties 3 and 1. In particular, consider the rectangle $R$ with the same top, bottom, and left edge as $B$, but with right edge at the vertical line
$$
x = b + \frac{a(L)}{2(d - c)}
$$
Since this is a rectangle, by Property 5 it must have measure equal to its width times its height, or
$$
a(R) = \left(\frac{a(L)}{2(d - c)}\right)(d - c) = \frac{a(L)}{2}
$$
But this means that, by Property 3, $a(R - L) = a(R) - a(L) = \frac{a(L)}{2} - a(L)  = -\frac{a(L)}{2}$, which is a contradiction since no measures can be negative by Property 1.
This shows that all vertical line segments have measure zero, and from there you can proceed as you describe in the question.
